# Getting error when trying to write on a file open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I am trying to write on the pdf file after creating it through intent but I am getting a permission denied error.

```
open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

the intent i am using to create the file

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE,userInputFileName);
        ActivityForresults.launch(intent);
```

the code inside the ActivityForresults

```
   Intent data = result.getData();
                        String path = data.getData().getPath();
                        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

                        File file = new File(root, userInputFileName);

                        try {
                            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file); 
                            pdfDocument.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

I have added install time permission

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I have also added run time permission

```
  String[] galleryPermissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS};
        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(getActivity(), galleryPermissions)) {
            Log.i("local-dev", "permissions are granted");
        } else {
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "Access for storage",
                    101, galleryPermissions);
        }
```

Comment: A `Uri` is not a file. Use `ContentResolver` and `openOutputStream()` to get an `OutputStream` on the content location identified by the `Uri`. You can then write your content there, rather than trying to use `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you pls explain with example

Comment: Here is [an entire free book on Android app development](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/). Using the Storage Access Framework, is covered in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-content-001.html). Using `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` specifically is covered in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-files-004). Those chapters include both [Java](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java) and [Kotlin](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin) samples.